# Puppet on WIndows: creating a resource only if a registry entry is (not) present

Tags: windows, puppet

I need to create a resource (a SCOM agent management group) only if a specific registry setting is not present.

The statement itself is simple but the class doesn't contain any built-in conditional checks (similar to "unless =>" in exec class).  The statement fails on SCOM management server because there is no SCOM agent installed. I want to prevent execution of the statement on such servers.

SCOM management server can be identified by presence of specific registry settings. If there any way to check that presence in "if", "unless" or other conditional statements? I know it's possible to write a custom fact and use it along with "if" but I don't know anything about Rubi and have no time to dive in. I need something simpler. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a resource (a SCOM agent management group) only if a
> specific registry setting is not present.

Well that's part of the problem right there.  You ought to know what machine is *supposed* to host a SCOM management server, and avoid declaring the agent management group based on that machine's identity.  You especially ought to know that if you have Puppet managing the management server, too, but even if you don't, this oughtn't to be something that you're figuring out dynamically at runtime.

But since you are ...

> The statement itself is simple but the class doesn't contain any
> built-in conditional checks (similar to "unless =>" in exec class).

If the resource that you want to apply conditionally does not have any built-in conditional checks that serve the purpose, then Puppet conditional statements such as `if` and `case` are the most likely options.

> SCOM management server can be identified by presence of specific
> registry settings. If there any way to check that presence in "if",
> "unless" or other conditional statements?

Puppet conditional statements are evaluated during catalog building, on the Puppet server.  What it knows about client nodes is limited to what your node classification, external (Hiera) data, and node facts convey to it.

> I know it's possible to write a custom fact and use it along with "if"
> but I don't know anything about Rubi and have no time to dive in. I
> need something simpler.

Custom facts are not hard to write, but for this purpose, you might find it easier to use an [*external* fact](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/external_facts.html), which on Windows can be implemented via a PowerShell script or batch file.  If that's not simple enough for you, then we're back to Puppet needing to know based on node identity.  That would manifest as having a different node block for the SCOM server or having different node-specific Hiera data for that node.

Comment: I know the theory but I hoped there is some default mechanism (like a pre-built fact) allowing to query the registry. It's difficult to apply different Puppet settings on SCOM servers (or it's rather kind of impossible when you have a dynamically changing environment consisting of several thousand servers managed by hundreds of application support teams). OK, then I have no choice but to resort to creating a custom fact.

Comment: @Evgeny, Puppet doesn't provide such a thing, but if you don't already know about it then the standard Windows [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) program might be of interest to you.  That would make it pretty easy to write an appropriate external fact in PowerShell, or even as a bat or cmd file.

Comment: yes, I've already created a possible resolution of the issue with a custom fact written in Powershell (actually, native PS commandlets are more convenient than old DOS commands). The problem is, it's a set approach at our environment to write facts in Rubi (which I don't know), so now I'm discussing with architects if a PS script is acceptable. If not, I'll have to ask someone to rewrite the fact in Rubi. Anyways, the link to the documentation was helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment this due to rep, but writing custom facts is easy, here is a an example. You will obv need to update the registry key to the correct path.

```
osfamily = Facter.value('osfamily')
case osfamily
when 'windows'
  Facter.add('custom_fact') do
    setcode do
      begin
        value = nil
        Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\ServerInfo') do |regkey|
          value = regkey['value_name'].downcase
        end
        value
      rescue
        nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your puppet code you can include or exclude resources based on the value.

```
if $facts['custom_fact'] {
  # Do something
}
```

Comment: ffalor, no doubt it's easy for you but I'm not a Rubi programmer. :) Thanks, noted. Should your architects decline my feeble attempt to use Powershell, I'll resort to Rubi and use this sample.

Comment: The above snippet will work for adding any registry key fact. Also if you're planning to write puppet code, i'd highly encourage you to look into ruby.